# mdc-fab background mdc-theme-secondary

Tags: css, web, material-components

Have the following in my Head tag

```
<style>
:root {
--mdc-theme-primary: #64ba69;
--mdc-theme--primary-light: #96ed98;
--mdc-theme--primary-dark: #31893d;
--mdc-theme--secondary: #e55100;
--mdc-theme--secondary-light: #ff833a;
--mdc-theme--secondary-dark: #ab1a00;
}
</style>
```

I can see that primary works for below with computed results 
background-color: rgb(100, 186, 105); = #64ba69

```
.mdc-button--raised:not(:disabled), .mdc-button--unelevated:not(:disabled) {
background-color: var(--mdc-theme-primary, #3f51b5);
}
```

But secondary does not work for below mdc-fab as get computed results 
background-color:rgb(255, 64, 129); = #ff4081

```
.mdc-fab {
background-color: var(--mdc-theme-secondary, #ff4081);
}
```

Not sure why ? https://codepen.io/webiflex/pen/rYKaNm

Answer (score 0):

Please see below answer , it was my mistake on the "You have an extra dash in some of the theme property names."
E.g.:
--mdc-theme--secondary
should be:
--mdc-theme-secondary

[Answer](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/issues/1642)